# Designing a Java class to present fractions correctly

Tags: java, fractions

I have created a Fraction Class that does various things such as the addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, greatest common denominator, etc...

There is one part that I am lost on.

I need to make a method that returns a String version of the numerator over the denominator using hyphens to separate them and I need the hyphens to equal the length of the denominator and the numerator to be centered.

For example:

the fraction 3/4  would be 3 with a hyphen under it and the 4 under the hyphen

and something like 5/50000 would be a 5 centered above the 3rd out of 5 hyphens and then the 50000 under the hyphens.

To calculate the number of hyphens that I need, I have come up with:

```
int hyphenLength = String.valueOf(this.denominator).length();
```

So far the only thing that I have thought of doing is running a for loop in the String but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried? You seem very close to solving it yourself, go step by step.

Comment: What's your problem then? It seems that you are asking how to calculate number of hyphens to use but you actually wrote the correct solution for that... What is the problem you are facing then?

Comment: I have been thinking about the ways to finish this for hours now. 

I set my hyphenLength to be the length of the denominator so all of the numbers in the denominator have a hyphen above them.

I just do not know how to transcribe this hyphenLength to printing the hyphens themselves. 

I know how many hyphens that I need, but I am unclear as to how to implement this into this String method....

Comment: ic, if that's the problem, here comes the answer  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just asking "how to create n-number of hyphens base on an int value", here is some ways you may look into:

There is no direct way in Java to do.  You have some way to do, the easiest way is as you said, by a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hyphenLength; ++i) {
  resultStringBuilder.append('-');
}
```

Another way is to make use of Arrays.fill():

```
char[] hyphenArray = new char[hyphenLength];
Arrays.fill(hyphenArray, '-');
String resultString = new String(hyphenArray);
```

If you can make use of Apache Commons Langs, you can use StringUtils.leftPad() or rightPad():

```
String resultString = StringUtils.leftPad("myData", hyphenLength, '-');
```

Comment: but next time it is better if you can be clear and focus on your problem.  Like this time, all the fraction things is in fact irrelevant.  You are simply having problem in generating a string with hyphens, with length base on an integer.

Comment: I will take that into consideration for my next question, whenever that is. Thanks again